# Call some function in Angular4 before any other component/service initialization?

Tags: angular

I have many components and services in my angular solution. When my angular solution is running, many GET/POST calls are happening. I just want to pass some token with all requests.

So what I did, in my Web API, I have created one function which will return some token, and that token I am planning to pass with each GET/POST calls.

I have 2 methods, GetToken and ValidateToken.

What I want is, GetToken method should call first before any other service call or component initialization. So that I can pass received token with all other GET/POST calls.

Can anybody tell me that how I can do that?

Comment: `APP_INITIALIZER` :)

Comment: Thanks, its worked.